# SecureCRT: Double-click selection for IP Address

Tags: ssh

Whenever I double click an IP address in [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) it only grabs to octet I have clicked on, not the whole thing.

E.g. double click `1.2.3.4` will only select `1`, not the whole thing.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add word delimiter to your default session:

```
` ~!@#$%^&*()+=:;>,\[]{}|'-_
```

[image: SecureCRT terminal word delimiter]